# Which loop should I use when the condition in while loop involves a variable which gets value inside the loop?

Tags: c, loops

I want to know how do I use use loop when a variable for example . It should loop until a encounters a '*' if the stdin is from a file. As long it is getting value of a it should iterate.

```
    while(a!='*')
   {
         scanf("%d",&a);
         ...
           ....
          ....
         ....

      }
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you want "%d" for the format specifier for this?

Comment: Yea that's the problem a is an integer and * is not :|

Comment: @Learner (and WhozCraig too) no, that is actually not a problem. `char` is an integral type as well. In fact, in the C standard library, most functions returning a character code return `int`. `'*'` is just fine for assigning to an integer (not in the case of `scanf()`, because there's no implicit type conversion through pointers, but when there is, it's correct).

Comment: @H2CO3 I realize that, but its the difference between storing a 0 and a '0'. Though now I want to see if `%d` actually *parses* a '*', 'cause I didn't think it did. hmjd's answer is what I was going toward.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, that's correct, `"%d"` won't make `scanf()` expect a non-integer character sequence. Just for clarification sake :)

Comment: @H2CO3 Further, clang immediately flags it as Warning: "%d" format specifier expects 'int \*' but the argument is 'char \*'. Edit: as I suspected, it will not consume the asterisk when scanning a '*' with '%d'. the `scanf()` just returns 0.

Comment: @WhozCraig Of course it does, but OP may have misinterpreted what... he said.

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah, likely so. there is no easy validation (until this whole thing is done is C++ =P)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to terminate immediately you read a `'*'`, how about

```
for (;;) {
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a == '*') {
        break;
    }
    ....
}
```

Or, if `'*'` is the last value you should process, you could use

```
do {
    scanf("%d", &a);
    ....
} while (a != '*');
```

Note that I've taked the suggestion from WhozCraig and Armin and changed your `scanf` line to pass the address of `a`.  If `a` is already a pointer type, the comparisons should change instead to dereference it - e.g. `*a == '*'`.  (In the latter case, you'd also need to be sure to have allocated the memory `a` pointed to.)

Comment: my answer going to be 1st one. +1

Comment: Are you sure it's scanf("%d",a) not scanf("%d",&a)

Comment: @Armin I'd copied the `scanf` from the question.  You're almost certainly correct that the question contains a typo however.  Answer now updated.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
char a;
while (scanf("%c", &a) == 1 && a != '*')
{
}
```

Changed format specifier to `%c`, passed in address of `a` and checked return value of `scanf()` to ensure a valid `char` was read.

Comment: But I am taking int values in a before  * , as soon as it reads '*' instead of any int value it should terminate

Comment: @Learner You can't validate the char read is a `'*'` unless you actually *read* it, and "%d" will not do so. Thus the real problem I think you're facing. Trying to validate with "%d" will return 0 on *anything* not contributory to the `int` being read, not just an asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use a do { } while loop instead.

Comment: but in do while it would check the condition in the end , so even if i enter m =* , it would run the code then check the condition